# Getting a pointer to a memory address from a different pointer C

Tags: c, memory-management, mmap, pointer-arithmetic

I'm writing my own memory allocater. I'm getting a pointer to mapped memory from mmap. From there, I want to be able to get a pointer to a different part of that mapped memory (like x bytes away from the current pointer). How can I do this? Memory management is very confusing to me.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic

Comment: Could you give me an example of obtaining the pointer that is 16 bytes away from the current pointer p?

Comment: Assuming your memory allocator is `void *p` then `char *q = (char*)p + 16;`

Comment: The type `char` is by definition one byte, so convert your `void*`s to `char*`s and then `p+16` will be 16 bytes away from `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mmap` gives you a `void*` and C doesn't allow pointer arithmetic with those, but you can cast it to `char*` and then just add the number of bytes you want, e.g. `mypointer + 16`.

If you cast the pointer to a larger type (like `int*`), pointer arithmetic adds multiples of the size of that type.  For example, if you add 16 to an `int*`, you're adding enough bytes for 16 `int` values (so 64 bytes, assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4).

Comment: I assume I can cast the `char*` back to a `void*` once I'm finished with the arithmetic?

Comment: @MatthewVanlandingham your commented case was 16 bytes but if that were 13 you could be creating an alignment issue, if the pointer you cast back to `void*` is later cast to, say `int*`.

Comment: Alignment is a different can of worms, and is an issue regardless of whether you cast directly from `char*` to `int*`, or take a detour through `void*` along the way.

Comment: Gotcha. I used 16 for a reason because I'm making sure all requests are aligned on 16-byte addresses! Thank you though!